# Where is an option set value's description stored in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am working on a report that pulls some data from CRM and for some reason the real value text I need is in the description of the option set choice. For the life of me I can not find it in the entity's StringMap's, or attributes's views. Help!!
[image]

Comment: Updated the answer, read it incorrectly the first time around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I initially read the question incorrectly which prompted me to go down the wrong path. To get the "Description" use the following query:

```sql
SELECT  DISTINCT ATTR.NAME, LOCLAB.LABEL AS DESCRIPTION
  FROM [ORG_MSCRM].[MetadataSchema].[Entity] ENT
      LEFT JOIN [ORG_MSCRM].[METADATASCHEMA].[ATTRIBUTE] ATTR 
        ON ENT.ENTITYID = ATTR.ENTITYID
      LEFT JOIN [ORG_MSCRM].[METADATASCHEMA].[ATTRIBUTEPICKLISTVALUE] ATTRPICK
        ON ATTR.OPTIONSETID = ATTRPICK.OPTIONSETID
      LEFT JOIN [ORG_MSCRM].[METADATASCHEMA].[LOCALIZEDLABEL] LOCLAB
        ON LOCLAB.OBJECTID = ATTRPICK.ATTRIBUTEPICKLISTVALUEID
WHERE ENT.OBJECTTYPECODE ='2' --contact
AND ATTR.NAME = 'GENDERCODE' --attributename
AND LOCLAB.OBJECTCOLUMNNAME = 'DESCRIPTION'
```

Comment: This is a solid answer.  The only thing I would add is specifying the entity in the StringMap query in case there is an attribute with the same schema name on another table.

Comment: @Zach updated the answer with a filter condition to narrow down the entity.

Comment: Can you add the table reference to "LABEL" for reference as to where exactly the value is. Other than that it does answer the question, thanks. I have got to say that is quite a few steps to get 1 piece of data with a 1 to 1 relation to another table.

Comment: @TommyHolman updated the answer with the table multi part identifier.